# How to share desktop in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I'm a bit lost. I have never used VNC before, and I have trouble now connecting from my laptop to the workstation. Both machines are Ubuntu 14.04. To play around, I first went to "enable desktop sharing" and enabled desktop sharing on the workstation:

[image]

Then I started the remmina client. I entered the server name, otherwise left everything as it was (for example, RDP as the protocol name), and clicked on "Connect". The client *seems* to connect, i.e. there is a window created, and if I disconnect my laptop from the network or mistype the server name, no window is created.

However, the window is all black. Nothing happens. On the server side, the icon of the server should light up, the server should ask me for confirmation. No such thing happens. I have no idea where to look for error messages and / or log files.

Comment: Ubuntu uses vnc instead of RDP. Desktop sharing uses vnc. Change this in Remmina

Answer (score 1):

Always try to simplify your problem: first turn off everything that could cause problems (like security or notification)

Then in your remmina client, change the RDP protocol to the VNC protocol and try again.

After that works, turn on the notification, then the security...

;-)